# How does recursive function in C works

Tags: c, function, recursion

Function fun(n) is defined as such:

```
fun(n) = 1                 (if n <=1)
fun(n) = fun(n/2)          (if n is even)
fun(n) = 2*fun((n-1)/3)    (if n> and n is odd)
```

I'm trying to write a recursive function to compute and return the result. I just started learning recursion, I got kind of lost while doing this function. Can someone correct me and explain to me? Thanks!

Here's what I did:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <math.h>

int fun(int n);

int main()
{
    int num;

    printf("\nEnter a number: ");
    scanf("%d", num);
    printf("Result = %d\n", fun(num));
    return 0;
}

int fun(int n)
{
    if (n <= 1)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    else if (n % 2 == 0)
    {
        return fun(n / 2);
    }

    else if ((n > 1) && (n % 2 == 0))
    {
        return 2 * fun((n - 1) / 3);
    }
}
```

Expected output:

```
Enter a number: 13
Result = 2

Enter a number: 34
Result = 4
```

Output I'm getting instead:

```
Enter a number: 13
Result = 1

Enter a number: 34
Result = 1
```

Comment: Did you missed `&` before `num` while typing in `scanf("%d", num);`?

Comment: Learn recursion then *unlearn* it. It's normally better to use a loop.

Comment: Your third condition should be `else if ((n > 1) && (n % 2 != 0))` instead of `else if ((n > 1) && (n % 2 == 0))`

Comment: @Aliou shouldn't the third condition simply be `else` (or no else at all, just the body that's there)? All other possibilities have been exhausted already.

Comment: @mah Yes you are right.

Comment: @haccks if he did it will probably crash and not give his results

Comment: @Bathsheba No need to unlearn right? Isn't recursion better than explicit stack in quicksort, tree traversal etc? Also, how'd we do this function in question iteratively?

Comment: @v3ga: hence *normally*. Quicksort has a logarithmic convergence so recursion works well. Factorial, binomial coefficient calculations etc. are ruinously expensive to solve recursively.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`scanf` takes a *pointer* to `int` as argument for `%d`, i.e.,

```
scanf("%d", &num);
```

Also, your function `fun` does not handle all cases and may fall off the bottom:

```
if (n <= 1)
{
    return 1;
}
else if (n % 2 == 0)
{
    return fun(n / 2);
}
else if ((n > 1) && (n % 2 == 0))
{
    return 2 * fun((n - 1) / 3);
}
```

The last `else if` condition is never met, because the previous check for `n % 2 == 0` already returns in that case. Also the `n > 1` is pointless because the first `n <= 1` returns in all other cases.

You can simply make it:

```
else
{
    return 2 * fun((n - 1) / 3);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The culprit is the last `else if` condition. Change it to:

```
else if ((n % 2) != 0)
```

Comment: or just remove the else completely since all other conditions have already been checked and rejected.

Answer (score 1):

The condition that n is odd is written wrong here. You wrote the same thing as for when n is even.

Its probably better to explicitly make the cases disjoint so you always return and there's no warning, like this:

```
int fun(int n)
{
    if(n <= 1)
        return 1;
    if(n % 2 == 0)
        return fun(n/2);
    //No need for a condition, we know the last one must be satisfied
    return 2 * fun((n-1)/3);
}
```

or, add another "default" case that indicates there was some error.

Answer (score 1):

I think last `if` should be:

```
else if ((n > 1) && (n % 2 != 0))
```

Notice the `!=` instead of `==`.

Answer (score 0):

The third condition

```
else if ((n > 1) && (n % 2 == 0))
```

is wrong, but instead of fixing it just you `else` no `else if` - because all other conditions were checked already.